# Why is the dry run of finding prime number in a given range not working as expected?

Tags: primes

```
n=int(input("Enter a number"))
for num in range(2,n+1):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if(num%i==0):
            break
    else:
        print(num,end="")
```

Here is the dry run-:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GfzI.jpg

**Everything is fine except for 2 where I am not getting 2 as output. What has gone wrong here? I don't understand what is gone wrong here?**

Comment: always post code as text. if i can't access imgur, i can't understand your post. and reread carefully your question: your programming language is never mentioned, not even in the tags. people that answer questions usually follow tags

Comment: that imgur stuff isn't a code my dear friend, it is dry run which can be only handwritten

Answer (score 1):

2 mod 2 is 0, so your loop breaks.

Instead of checking if your number is divisible by every integer up to the number, try checking it only against the array of primes you have already found - this should be more efficient, and also give the output you are looking for :-)

EDIT:
Here is some code I wrote in JavaScript as an example of my suggestion:

```js
let n = 5
let foundPrimes = []
for (let num = 2; num <= n; num++){
    let divisible = false
    for (let prime of foundPrimes){
        if (num%prime == 0) {
            divisible = true
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!divisible) {
        foundPrimes.push(num)
    }
}
console.log(foundPrimes)
```

Comment: The code def gives the output I am looking for. The dry run doesn't give it.

Comment: I don't know your programming language, so I woudn't know why your code behaves diffrently from your dry run (the dry run makes sense to me).
I have edited my answer to include a JavaScript example of what I mean though :-)